# printing a list in excel from python

Tags: python, excel

I want to print my output from for loop to an excel sheet. One tricky thing is that i want it to print according to the heading i have already given(i dont mind giving heading in python also). So here are tha values i want to print:

```
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,3]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,2]
[0,0,0,3]
```

each value represents [RD,RW,ND,NW] variables in each list. Is there any way i can print these values in excel with the given variables as heading?

Comment: What does "printing in excel" mean? Maybe you're looking for csvwriter, xlsxwriter, etc?

Comment: yes@MateenUlhaq i did try xlsxwriter but i was able to print only in vertical order and if i change the order values arent printing in an excel sheet.

Comment: i dont know about csvwriter since these values are the output of a for loop which i want to be written to an excel file. i am pretty new to python so i have no idea about integrating excel with python

Answer (score 0):

Use Panda Library there are lots of examples